# MySQLI Connect Error Shows Password

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, opencart

I have a website running on opencart which uses command Mysqli connect to connect to database, now the problem i am facing is if due to some error it is not able to connect or lets say i change the password for my database user my Output shows a fatal error which includes the password used to connect also.

Error i Receive

> Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (28000/1045): Access denied for user
>   'saledart_admin'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in
>   /home2/saledart/public_html/system/database/mysqli.php on line 6
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Error:
>   Could not make a database link (1045) Access denied for user
>   'saledart_admin'@'localhost' (using password: YES)' in
>   /home2/saledart/public_html/system/database/mysqli.php:9 Stack trace:> #0 /home2/saledart/public_html/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-system_library_db.php(13):
>   DBMySQLi->__construct('localhost', 'saledart_admin', '**SqlPassword**',
>   'saledart_db') #1 /home2/saledart/public_html/index.php(44):
>   DB->__construct('mysqli', 'localhost', 'saledart_admin',
>   '**SqlPassword**', 'saledart_db') #2 {main} thrown in
>   /home2/saledart/public_html/system/database/mysqli.php on line 9

As you can see such error displays my sql password, i want to know if there is a way that my password is not shwn ever due to any error like this.

I hope i was able to make myself clear.

Regards

PS: I Can resolve this error since this is coming since i have changed the Database users password but my point is that even old password should not be shown such easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use **php** `try catch` , its  Exception handling is used to change the normal flow of the code execution if a specified error  occurs.

```
try {
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");

    if(!$conn) {
        throw new Exception('Failed');
    }
} catch(Exception $e) {
    echo 'Server error. Please try again some time.';
    die;

}
```

Comment: That should have solved the problem but by any chance you know how to implement it in Opencart?

Comment: This is a nice and perfect fit answer but please improve it a little by explaining (at least in short) what is the `try-catch` block and how it is used with exceptions so that anybody new to the topic can immediately understand it and not just *copy-paste* without thinking. Thanks!

Comment: That's a VERY BAD approach, which disregards the precious value of error message. Should never be used.

Answer (score -1):

Another solution:

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_OFF);
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-report.php#127612

I can't believe they made it that stupid to reveal user and password.

Comment: it ain't stupid. you just need to learn how to deal with error messages

Comment: @YourCommonSense lol you are recalling me the joke about Microsoft. Do you know how Microsoft changes the light bulb? They make the darkness as new standard.